# How do I: Implement a n-level nested gridview?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, data-binding, nested-controls

I am not the gratest when it comes to implementing UX. I looked around on the internet for an implementation of a nested gridview or nested reapeater control. Most of the demos used an sql datasource object. Nowadays I dont see anyone using an sqldatasource. In my scenario I will be using Object Datasource or would be databinding manually. The source of data is a WCF service on wsHttpBinding.

I will really appreciate if someone could provide me some tips/web resource for solving this problem.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telerik do an excellent grid that can be populated using WCF (I use this, it is v fast):
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/clientbinding/defaultcs.aspx

... and hierarchy:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/hierarchy/hierarchyloadmodeclient/defaultcs.aspx

Haven't combined the two but looking at the object model, I'm sure it could be done.

Comment: We are not buying any 3rd party controls and I am stuck. Have been living in DAL and Biz layers all my life recently surfacing up